# What can I do as far as controlling battery charging via a "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery"

Tags: windows-10, battery, battery-life, acpi

I noticed that sometimes when my laptop is plugged in it says "Plugged in not charging" - searching around I see all sorts of ways to disable this by removing the "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery" driver from the device manager - however I would rather use this to my advantage instead - is there a way for me to see why the battery is not charging, and/or configure the reasons, or prevent the battery from charging (via software) when plugged in but at a sufficient level?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `powercfg` command-line options. For example:

- Generate a battery life report

  ```
    powercfg -batteryreport
  ```

Here is the full list of options:

```
Command List:
  /LIST, /L          Lists all power schemes.

  /QUERY, /Q         Displays the contents of a power scheme.

  /CHANGE, /X        Modifies a setting value in the current power scheme.

  /CHANGENAME        Modifies the name and description of a power scheme.

  /DUPLICATESCHEME   Duplicates a power scheme.

  /DELETE, /D        Deletes a power scheme.

  /DELETESETTING     Deletes a power setting.

  /SETACTIVE, /S     Makes a power scheme active on the system.

  /GETACTIVESCHEME   Retrieves the currently active power scheme.

  /SETACVALUEINDEX   Sets the value associated with a power setting
                     while the system is powered by AC power.

  /SETDCVALUEINDEX   Sets the value associated with a power setting
                     while the system is powered by DC power.

  /IMPORT            Imports all power settings from a file.

  /EXPORT            Exports a power scheme to a file.

  /ALIASES           Displays all aliases and their corresponding GUIDs.

  /GETSECURITYDESCRIPTOR
                     Gets a security descriptor associated with a specified
                     power setting, power scheme, or action.

  /SETSECURITYDESCRIPTOR
                     Sets a security descriptor associated with a
                     power setting, power scheme, or action.

  /HIBERNATE, /H     Enables and disables the hibernate feature.

  /AVAILABLESLEEPSTATES, /A
                     Reports the sleep states available on the system.

  /DEVICEQUERY       Returns a list of devices that meet specified criteria.

  /DEVICEENABLEWAKE  Enables a device to wake the system from a sleep state.

  /DEVICEDISABLEWAKE Disables a device from waking the system from a sleep
                     state.

  /LASTWAKE          Reports information about what woke the system from the
                     last sleep transition.

  /WAKETIMERS        Enumerates active wake timers.

  /REQUESTS          Enumerates application and driver Power Requests.

  /REQUESTSOVERRIDE  Sets a Power Request override for a particular Process,
                     Service, or Driver.

  /ENERGY            Analyzes the system for common energy-efficiency and
                     battery life problems.

  /BATTERYREPORT     Generates a report of battery usage.

  /SLEEPSTUDY        Generates a diagnostic system power transition report.

  /SRUMUTIL          Dumps Energy Estimation data from System Resource Usage
                     Monitor (SRUM).

  /SYSTEMSLEEPDIAGNOSTICS
                     Generates a diagnostic report of system sleep transitions.

  /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT Generates a diagnostic system power transition report.

  /POWERTHROTTLING   Control power throttling for an application.
```

**References**

- [Powercfg command-line options | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)
- [Managing Power Options as a non-administrator – Aaron Margosis' Non-Admin, App-Compat and Sysinternals WebLog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2005/02/09/managing-power-options-as-a-non-administrator/)
- [powercfg – Useful if you know the GUIDS! – Richard Smith](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richardsmith/2007/11/29/powercfg-useful-if-you-know-the-guids/)
- [Configure power settings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/configure-power-settings)
- [Fine-Tune a Custom Power Plan | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/fine-tune-a-custom-power-plan-technicalreference)